# Does cdi producer take class scope

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

Hello my question is does a produce for example on a applicationscoped bean produces instances also applicationscoped? Does it take its class scope or is always dependent?

Comment: You can check (with code): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559523/creating-application-scoped-class-member-with-a-producer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification treats producer methods as beans (basically, producer is a definiton of *how you create an instance of given bean type*). Therefore a rule applies, that if no scope is provided, `@Default` is assumed.

Hence the answer to your question is - **the producer scope is `@Default` if none is specified. There is no link between producer scope and the scope of the bean on which it is declared.**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public MyBean {

  @Produces //this will produce @Dependent
  public Foo produceDependent() {
    return new Foo();
  }

  @Produces
  @RequestScoped //produces the scope you define
  public Bar produceReqScopedBean() {
    return new Bar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on

Produces @Dependent

```
@ApplicationScoped
class Bean {
    @Produces
    public String producesString(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Produces @ApplicationScoped

```
@ApplicationScoped
class Bean {
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public String producesString(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Produces @RequestScoped

```
@ApplicationScoped
class Bean {
    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public String producesString(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```