# Creating application scoped class member with a producer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, hazelcast

Is it true to say that in the code bellow, the Hazelcast instance will be application scoped ?

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Producer {

    private HazelcastInstance instance;

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }

    @Produces
    public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This solution:

1. Ensure produced been are application scoped.
2. Provide graceful Hazelcast shut down.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Producer {

    private HazelcastInstance instance;

    private Producer() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void beforeDestroy() {
        if(instance != null) {
            instance.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You `Producer` bean will be application scoped, that much is clear.
However, **`HazelnutInstance` bean will be `@Dependent`.**

Therefore, if you, somewhere in your code, do `@Inject HazelnutInstance` it will inject a dependent instance from CDI viewpoint.

But you always return the same instance, never create new object in your producer, so *theoretically*, you are sharing that one instance.

However, look out for bean lifecycles! `@Dependent` beans will be destroyed when the bean where they were injected is destroyed. So now assume it comes to such destruction attempt - Weld will try to destroy your dependent bean and will call `@PreDestroy` (on "classic" beans) or `@Disposes` (on beans with producers) method on it.

Therefore, in your case, if there is a [disposer method](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#disposer_method) somewhere, which handles `HazelcastInstance`, that might cause a trouble as it would be invoked every time Weld attempts to destroy/dispose of that dependent bean.

IMO you would be better off if you make `HazelcastInstance` application scoped. E.g.

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
   return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the assumption I was doing in my comment to @Nico. I was expecting a formal answer with no guess. Will dig into the specs and / or unit test and post an answer. Thanks sharing your thoughts.

Comment: You're welcome. What would be a formal enough answer for you? I am not aware of making any guesses - I cannot tell if it will break you app since you cannot know of your bean uses any predestroy calls. Also switching to `@ApplicationScoped @Produces` should be viable in your case (unless the bean is unproxyable).

Comment: The relevant part of the CDI-1.2 spec is 2.4.4: "When no scope is explicitly declared by annotating the bean class **or producer method** or field the scope of a bean is defaulted. ... If the bean does not declare any stereotype with a declared default scope, **the default scope
for the bean is `@Dependent`**."

Comment: @HeyStackExchange Edited answer, in case of producers, its `@Disposes` which may cause headached. `@Predestroy` is harmless as it doesn't work for producers. So as long as you don't use disposer methods, this solution should be sound.

Comment: I think you could also bind interceptors to the bean using a Stereotype annotation on the producer method. In that case, any `PreDestroy` interceptors would also fire when the dependent bean goes out of scope.

Note that you **can't** use interceptor binding annotations on the producer method directly to bind interceptors.

Comment: No you cannot intercept producer-created beans, in CDI 1.2 it's plain impossible unless you implement it everything yourself (the internals that is). In 2.0 there were added means to handle that - InterceptionFactory -> http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#interception_factory

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to get a unit test prove the expected behaviors.

Code and results can be found below.

***Environment***

UT launched against WebLogic 12.2.1 remote container using arquillian

**1. ApplicationScoped class and producer, new instance**: PASS

As expected the test pass: the produced bean is application scoped, and as such the same instance is injected.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Producer {

    private Producer() {}

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }
}
```

**2. ApplicationScoped class and Dependent producer, new instance**: FAIL

As expected the test fail: the produced bean being `@Dependent`, a different instance is injected. (Note: `@Dependent` being the default scope, it can or not be present, the same result will be the same).

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Producer {

    private Producer() {}

    @Produces
    public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }
}
```

**3. ApplicationScoped class and Dependent producer, post construct instance**: PASS

As expected the test pass: the produced `instance` bean is `@Dependent`. However, its lifecycle is indirectly bound to the `Producer` lifecycle (through `@PostConstruct` called once) and as such, the same instance is returned at each call, and dereferenced when the Producer bean is destructed.

***Note***: Hazelcast hasn't been gracefully shut down in this implementation.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Producer {

    private HazelcastInstance instance;

    private Producer() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }

    @Produces
    public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**4. ApplicationScoped class and ApplicationScoped producer, post construct instance**: PASS

As expected the test pass: the produced bean is `@ApplicationScoped` and the same instance is returned during the application life cycle.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Producer {

    private HazelcastInstance instance;

    private Producer() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**5. Dependent class and ApplicationScoped producer, post construct instance**: PASS

This result is surprising: Producer is annotated `@Dependent`, its producer `@ApplicationScoped` and the result is that the same instance is returned by each Producer instance.
Reason: CDI use scoped contexts

```java
@Dependent
public class Producer {

    private HazelcastInstance instance;

    private Producer() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**6. Dependent class and producer, post construct instance**: FAIL

As expected the test fail: the produced bean being `@Dependent`, a different instance is injected. (Note: `@Dependent` being the default scope, it can or not be present, the same result will be the same) as each Producer instance will invoke its own `afterCreate` method, leading to different `instance` instances

```java
@Dependent
public class Producer {

    private HazelcastInstance instance;

    private Producer() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    }

    @Produces
    public HazelcastInstance getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Unit test**

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ProducerTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {

         // Import Maven runtime dependencies
        File[] files = Maven.resolver()
                            .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                            .importRuntimeDependencies()
                            .resolve()
                            .withTransitivity()
                            .asFile();
        // Create deploy file    
        WebArchive war =  ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, ProducerTest.class.getName() + ".war")
            .addClass(Producer.class)
            .addClass(ProducerTest.class)
            .addAsLibraries(files);

        // Show the deploy structure
        System.out.println(war.toString(true)); 

        return war;
    }

    @Inject
    private HazelcastInstance hzInstance1;

    @Inject
    private HazelcastInstance hzInstance2;

    @Before
    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
        assertEquals(emptySet(), getAllHazelcastInstances());
    }

    @Test
    public void producerTest() {
        assertTrue(hzInstance1.equals(hzInstance2));
    }
}
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://www.jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="wls-remote" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="wlHome">PATH_TO_WLSERVER_DIRECTORY</property>
            <property name="adminUrl">ADMIN_URL</property>
            <property name="adminUserName">USER_NAME</property>
            <property name="adminPassword">PASSWORD</property>
            <property name="target">TARGET_SERVER</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

**hazelcast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.5.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <group>
        <name>producer</name>
        <password>producer_pass</password>
    </group>

    <network>
        <port auto-increment="false">10710</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false" />
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member>localhost</member>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>

</hazelcast>
```

For the sake of the completeness, the POM

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>HeyStackExchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559523/scoped-instance</url>

    <name>Arquillian WLS 12.1.x/12.2.x - CDI Example</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

        <arquillian.version>1.1.5.Final</arquillian.version>

        <!-- JEE -->
        <jboss-javaee-7.0.version>1.1.0.Final</jboss-javaee-7.0.version>

        <!-- Arquillian -->
        <arquillian-wls-12.1.x.version>1.0.1.Final</arquillian-wls-12.1.x.version>

        <!-- Cache -->
        <hazelcast.version>3.8.3</hazelcast.version>

        <!-- UT -->
        <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <slf4j-api.version>1.7.25</slf4j-api.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.9</slf4j-log4j12.version>

    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JEE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss-javaee-7.0.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Arquillian -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1.x</artifactId>
            <!--artifactId>arquillian-wls-managed-12.1.x</artifactId -->
            <version>${arquillian-wls-12.1.x.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- UT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: 4) Isn't surprising, you just have to take into consideration **contexts**. E.g. the bean is `@ApplicationScoped` and hence lives in app context. If Weld is to return an instance of `HazelcastInstance` with app scope, it first checks the underlying context "storage" and if the bean was already created once, it will simply return the instance and not attempt to create a new one (you could verify this with some counter in your producer).

Comment: To add on top of that, the (**simplified!!**) flow of injection would be - check bean storage for given active context. If I have the bean, just return it (well, proxy in fact). If I don't have it - create new one, put it into storage, return proxy of this object. Therefore, with app scoped producer, you only need to invoke the producer once, and you store the result. **NOTE**: `@Dependent` behaves differently, there is no storage below, as you always want new instance which you bind to other bean.

Comment: @Siliarus That's the fact indeed. Added a note to mention the reason. Thanks for your contribution (up voted you).

Answer (score -2):

Yes the Producer will receive the Scope you applied with the Annotation `@ApplicationScoped`. This will result in only having one instance for the whole CDI Application. Every Request to the class `Producer` will come to the same instance of the class since it will be only initialized once and then kept active. Since the Producer is application scoped the instance of `Hazelcast`will not change, as long as you don't change it in the class itself ( e.g setter )

> An object which is defined as @ApplicationScoped is created once for the duration of the application.

*taken from [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/cdi-application-scope/README.html)*

Comment: I'm not sure. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242487/does-cdi-producer-take-class-scope. `@ApplicationScoped` is at the class level. The producer still need to be annotated with ApplicationScoped or it will default to `@Dependent`. But in this case, the `@Postconstruct` being part of the bean lifecyle may make the instance scope to be application scoped. I just want a confirmation on this assumption.

Comment: @HeyStackExchange No problem. The Workflow is the following: On Startup your Application Server will register all classes annotated with `@ApplicationScoped`. Since the producer you have shown is application scoped the `afterCreate()` will be called on startup and create the instance of `Hazelcast`. This is done once on Server startup and since the class will not be initialized again, the instance of `Hazelcast` in this producer stays the same. Afterwards only the `getInstance()` will be called once you want an instance with this producer.

Comment: @HeyStackExchange However if your class `Hazelcast` is not Application scoped you will be able to create infinite instances of Hazelcast **if not** getting them with the producer. ( I hope you understand what I try to get accross here, I am not sure if it is explained good ).
This all can be tested and verified with looking at the proxy of the received `Hazelcast` instance in the application.

Comment: @Nico There is no proxy/subclass if it's pure dependent bean (with no decorator/interceptor). There is no need for proxies if you are supposed to pass by new object each time you inject.

Comment: @Siliarus So my understanding that generally CDI uses proxy objects on injected instances is incorrect? Ups and thanks for telling me. Still to come back to my answer I think I am correct, could you also verify that or correct me?

Comment: Your assumption is correct for all `@NormalScope` scopes which is basically everything **except** `@Dependent` (and `@Singleton`).  Your answer is incomplete and in that untrue - see my answer. The added trick is with the lifecycle of dependent bean.

Comment: @Siliarus Thank you :)